# How to enable ipc-sysv-sem in Mac Sandboxing?

Tags: ipc, semaphore, appstore-sandbox, entitlements, sysv-ipc

I need to use IPC System V Semaphores (ipc-sysv-sem) in a Mac application. However, the Mac Sandboxing does not allow their usage. I obtain (in the mac console):

```
27/06/14 12:17:50,000 kernel[0]: Sandbox: MyApp(69513) deny ipc-sysv-sem
```

Does anyone now how to accept IPC System V Semaphores in a Mac Sandboxed application?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Apple says it's not possible:
https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/security/conceptual/AppSandboxDesignGuide/AppSandboxInDepth/AppSandboxInDepth.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011183-CH3-SW24

You can use POSIX semaphores, though.

Comment: Thanks. Do you hve any clue on how changing from System V semaphore to a POSIX one? In my case, the drivers of the Asus Xtion camera are using sysv-semaphores, therefore I cannot touch them in depth. The access a file called: /private/tmp/XnCore.Mutex.HostProtocolMutex1d27_0601@250_6.key

Just if this helps...

Comment: If you don't have access to the source code, I don't think you're going to be able to do anything :-(